# Fastest way to flatten data model from relational database

Tags: database, performance, rest, data-modeling

I am currently working on an application which stores data in a simple hierarchy. The model is similar to this (expressed in C#-like syntax):

```
class Box {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class Gadget {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int ParentBox { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have several thousand boxes, and I have zero or more gadgets that belong in a box. To access data, I have created a small REST API that allows me to query for either all boxes, or a subset of them. The response via the API is a data transfer object, that contains all of the gadgets that belong to the box. A typical JSON answer would be:

```
{ "Boxes": [
    { "Id: 1,
      "Gadgets": [
        { "Id": 100 }
        { "Id": 101 }
      ]
    },
    { "Id: 2,
      "Gadgets": [
        { "Id": 200 }
        { "Id": 201 }
      ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, turns out that performance is lousy. The logic for fetching the data is (again, in C#-like syntax):

```
var boxes = Db.Select<Boxes>();

foreach (var box in boxes) {
  var boxDto = new BoxDto();
  boxDto.Gadgets = ConvertToDto(Db.Select<Gadget>().Where(q => q.Box == box.Id));
}
```

I know that my solution is naive. I have tens of thousands of boxes, each with tens of gadgets in each box. My questions are:

- Are there any patterns for managing these kinds of relationships efficiently? I cannot be the first to have this problem, yet I am not finding anything on the web.
- Should I change the data model? If so, how?

Any ideas/feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that assuming you are using SQL Server, you can write a query that outputs XML. This way you can join the boxes and gadgets in the database and return an XML file that has the hierarchy you want.

When your application gets the XML, it's a quick process to turn that into JSON.

Alternatively, for *really* simply JSON, you can do string concatenation in TSQL. Basically compose your own JSON and return that from the stored procedure. It can get really nasty really fast if the hierarchy is complex though.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. However, first converting to XML and then back to JSON before transmitting it over the wire seems to cumbersome and expensive.